# Trying to load jQuery getScript function but button does not send information

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'ts probably something stupid, since i'm beginner with using JavaScript and jQuery, but the trouble is real. I have button inside bootstrap twitter modal, that's actually not important, since it's not working inside of a real page body aswell, but console shows no errors. I don't know how to describe my problem more, so i'll add some code and maybe someone can help. What i'd like to achieve is to load the script after button is pressed.

Scripts are loaded in this order:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/swisspaaritu.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
```

Inside swisspaaritu.js the top function is:

```
$('#savepdf').on('click', function() {
$.getScript('../js/swisspdf.js', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    // do some stuff after script is loaded
    console.log(data); //not displayed in console
    console.log(textStatus); //not displayed in console
} );
} );
```

Note that other functions in swisspaaritu.js work, just this function is creepy..

And that's the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="savepdf">Salvesta PDFina</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code, may be the path to swisspdf.js is wrong

```
$.getScript("../js/swisspdf.js")
 .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
 console.log("done :"+textStatus );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
 console.log("failed "+exception);
});
```

try adding fail to handle error, may be that may show something.